# couldn't print python 3 dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that takes an input from the user which is a key in the dictionary and print out the value that associated with the key. for example 
dic = {"hello":"hi"} so if the user enter hello the output should be hi.

here is my code

```
def translate(myText):       
    dic = {"Hello":"hi", "New":"old", "bad":"good", "happy":"sad"}
    for i in dic.items():
        if i == myText:
            answer = dic.values([myText])
            print(answer)

myInput= input("Enter a text to translate: ")
result = myInput.split()
translate(result)
```

I don't get any output with this code. also, I want to write more the one word, for example, if I type Hello new bad. I need to get hi old good. How can I print more than one value?

Thank you.

Comment: `dic.values([myText])` - What do you think this code does? I think you're misunderstanding how to index a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def translate(myText):

    dic = {"Hello":"hi", "New":"old", "bad":"good", "happy":"sad"}

    for word in myText:
        if word in dic:
            print dic[word]

myInput= input("Enter a text to translate: ")
result = myInput.split()
translate(result)
```

The main reason your initial code wasn't working is that `myInput.split()` makes `result` a list of strings rather than a list. Then you try to check `myText` against the keys in the dictionary - but they're strings, so they can never be equal to a list.

The beauty of dictionaries is that they let you look up a particular value immediately, without needing to iterate through the elements of the dictionary. The syntax is just `dic[key]`; you don't need `dic.values()` or `dic.items()` for this (those do something pretty different). To check whether a key is in the dictionary, you can just say `key in dic`. The code above iterates through every word in the input, checks if it's in the dictionary, and prints the value if so.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally what you're looking to do here is index a dictionary. This is done quite simply by writing the following:

```
value = dict[key]
```

More generally, if you're not sure whether or not a key existing in the dictionary you can use this syntax:

```
value = dict.get(key, default_value)
```

This will return the value associated with key if there is a value, otherwise value will be assigned the default value.

Finally, I feel very strongly that I should not give you a working code snippet. You're clearly in the early throes of learning python, well done! Welcome to the journey, but if SO helps too much then you'll never learn how to code. Here are some tips for changing your code:

- Don't make a call to `.items()`, the whole point of dictionaries is that you don't have to iterate through them to find what you're looking for
- If you want to call `split()` on your input, then you will get a list of strings. Make sure you loop through that list of strings if you want to check each of them.
- Try to rewrite your code using either the `dict[key]` syntax, or the `dict.get(key, default_value)` syntax. It will make it much cleaner
- Bonus points: try to write your function using `*args` as an input to avoid any external for loop. Only try this after you've got the rest working as this can be considered an intermediate python topic.

Comment: @ChristianDean yea, I didn't see the whole question. I've updated it to be much more complete and importantly have not given a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you print `i` at every for-loop, you can see the values like:

`('bad', 'good')
('happy', 'sad')
('New', 'old')
('Hello', 'hi')`

that represent with tuple, not dictionary.
It means, you can't get the specific value with some key, but you can get with index.

Also, to get every value with keys you entered, try to iterate your key list spliced by `split()` function, and call the functions `translate()` at every iterations.

If you want to get each value by your keys, you can write the code like:

```
def translate(myText):

    dic = {"Hello":"hi", "New":"old", "bad":"good", "happy":"sad"}
    answer = dic[myText]
    print(answer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myInput = input("Enter a text to translate: ")
    result = myInput.split()

    for key in result:
        translate(key)
```

plus)
I'm sorry to mislead your question, so i updated my answer with new code and fix typo.

Comment: Is there a reason you hard coded the key his function indexes, instead of using `myText`? Also, the OP wants to test if `myText` is in the dictionary first, to avoid an error. You should test this also, either using a conditional statement or (preferable) a `try/except` block.

Comment: More importantly, in this case it's obvious that OP is asking the wrong question. It's a case of the XY problem (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), so the answer shouldn't address this direct question.

Comment: @ChristianDean yes, my bad. I miss the last part of question. I've updated my answer with new codes.